# vba loop through files in folder and copy names if multiple conditions are met/not met

Tags: vba, excel, loops, directory, conditional-statements

I would like to loop through a folder and copy all the names of the excelfiles which does not contain "string1" in A6, "string2" in B6, "string3" in C6, "string4" in D6. Note all the conditions should be true (a AND statement).
The cells which should be tested are located in sheet 3, which is called "ProjectOperation".

The following code copy pase the filenames of all excel in a specific folder, however I have a hard time implementing the conditions. Please help.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SubDirList() 'Excel VBA process to loop through directories listing files
Dim sname As Variant
Dim sfil(1 To 1) As String
sfil(1) = "C:\Users\test" 'Change this path to suit.

For Each sname In sfil()
SelectFiles sname
Next sname

End Sub

Private Sub SelectFiles(sPath) 'Excel VBA to show file path name.
Dim Folder As Object
Dim file As Object
Dim fldr
Dim oFSO As Object
Dim i As Integer

'For Each file In Folder
 '       If checknameExistens(Folder.Files) Then

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Folder = oFSO.GetFolder(sPath)
i = 1
For Each fldr In Folder.SubFolders
SelectFiles fldr.Path
Next fldr

For Each file In Folder.Files
'If checknameExistens(Folder.Files) Then
Range("A6536").End(xlUp)(2).Value = file
i = i + 1
Next file

Set oFSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

The original code is from the following link: http://www.thesmallman.com/list-files-in-subdirectory/

Comment: Have you tried anything? Are those conditions ANDs or ORs?

Comment: And which sheet are you talking about, always the first one?

Comment: Yes I have tried different stuff, the latest is the outcommented part  

'For Each file In Folder
 '       If checknameExistens(Folder.Files) Then

But it did not work so I have deleted it. 

The conditions are AND's  and it should be sheet 3 named "ProjectOperation"

Comment: Then I would recommend to edit the post and add the additonal information. How do you know it's always sheet 3?

Comment: Ok I'll do that. 
That is a good question - It is either sheet 3 or the sheet called "ProjectOperation"

Answer (score 1):

First of all I changed the code which retrieves the files because it collects all file regardless if it is a excel file or not. I also changed it to a function which gives all the files back in a collection

```
Function SelectFiles(ByVal sPath As String, ByVal pattern As String) As Collection

Dim Folder As Object
Dim file As Object
Dim fldr
Dim oFSO As Object
Dim coll As New Collection

    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set Folder = oFSO.GetFolder(sPath)

    For Each fldr In Folder.SubFolders
        SelectFiles fldr.path, pattern
    Next fldr

    For Each file In Folder.Files
        If file.Name Like pattern Then
            coll.Add file
        End If
    Next file

    Set SelectFiles = coll

End Function
```

Then I used the following function to retrieve the contents of the files which you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51970004/excel-vba-to-extract-data-from-multiple-excel-files/51970915#51970915) resp. [here](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/a_vba_function_to_get_a_value_from_a_closed_file/)

```
Private Function GetValue(path, file, sheet, ref)
'   Retrieves a value from a closed workbook
Dim arg As String
    '   Make sure the file exists
    If Right(path, 1) <> "\" Then path = path & "\"
    If Dir(path & file) = "" Then
        GetValue = "File Not Found"
        Exit Function
    End If
    '   Create the argument
    arg = "'" & path & "[" & file & "]" & sheet & "'!" & _
          Range(ref).Range("A1").Address(, , xlR1C1)
    '   Execute an XLM macro
    GetValue = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)
    If IsError(GetValue) Then GetValue = ""

End Function
```

And this is the final result

```
Sub TestList()
Const SH_NAME = "ProjectOperation"
Dim sname As Variant
Dim coll As Collection
Dim s1 As String
Dim s2 As String
Dim s3 As String
Dim s4 As String
Dim i As Long

    sname = "...."     'Change this path to suit.

    Set coll = SelectFiles(sname, "*.xls*")

    For i = 1 To coll.Count
        s1 = GetValue(coll.Item(i).parentfolder, coll.Item(i).Name, SH_NAME, "A6")
        s2 = GetValue(coll.Item(i).parentfolder, coll.Item(i).Name, SH_NAME, "B6")
        s3 = GetValue(coll.Item(i).parentfolder, coll.Item(i).Name, SH_NAME, "C6")
        s4 = GetValue(coll.Item(i).parentfolder, coll.Item(i).Name, SH_NAME, "D6")
        If s1 = "string1" And s2 = "string2" And s3 = "string3" And s4 = "string4" Then
            Debug.Print coll.Item(i).path
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: First of all, Thank you very much for your response! :) 
However I can't get the code to work. Maby I didn't explain my problem correctly, or just don't understand the code.  
I'll explain in an example:
I have 3 excel documents named e1, e2 and e3.  e1 and e2 are identical (they have the same text in A6, B6, C6, D6) but e3 have different text in cell D6. Therefore I would like the workbookname of e3 to be listed in my VBA excel, since it does not meet the same conditions as the others. 

Thank you for your time! :)

Comment: I'd suggest to edit your post in order to make your problem clearer because according to your comment this seems to be different from what I understood. Anyway, I think, you could also use part of my code to do what you want as `SelectFiles` gives you a collection of all excel files and `GetValue`gives you the value of certain cells in an excel file. If you combine it according to your need it should work. You just have to adapt `TestList` which shoud not be that difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I worked with your existing code and have just added an If statement inside your loop (as well as a couple of declarations of new variables). Because you are now working with two files you need to properly reference the workbook and sheet whenever you refer to a range.

```
'...
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each file In Folder.Files
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(file)
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("ProjectOperation")
    If ws.Range("A6").Value = "string1" And ws.Range("B6").Value = "string2" And _
       ws.Range("c6").Value = "string3" And ws.Range("D6").Value = "string4" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Value = file 'workbook/sheet references may need changing
        i = i + 1
    End If
    wb.Close False
Next file
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'...
```